# Getting a date in the past using strtotime

Tags: php

```
$month = date('m', strtotime('-19 years'));
$day = date('d', strtotime('-19 years'));
$year = date('Y', strtotime('-19 years'));
```

This correctly gets me the month/day/year of 19 years ago, which on this day (Jan 08, 2021) is 01, 08, 2002 respectively. How could I do it for 19 years and one day ago? 19 years and a month ago? 19 years and a day and a month ago? etc.

For the first case (19 years and one day ago) `$month = date('m', strtotime('-19 years -1day'))` doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to work https://3v4l.org/A33D5v  Notice the timezone of the server is Central European Standard Time

Comment: @Steven  seems to work without space https://3v4l.org/tLuoc

Comment: @AbraCadaver then I retract my last comment!

Comment: @AbraCadaver You are right..it does work. I am struggling to remember why I had deemed it to be otherwise. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime()` takes a second argument, which is the base date to use for relative times. So you can subtract a day from now, then use `-19 years`

```
strtotime('-19 years', strtotime('-1 day'))
```

Comment: Yes but adding/subtracting seconds ignores daylight savings time etc `strtotime('-19 years', strtotime('-1 day'))` or similar. `strtotime('-1 day', strtotime('-19 years'))`

Comment: However it seems that OP's code works https://3v4l.org/tLuoc